# passing a date value from parent to child results in strange format in the child component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a value that is a date in one of my React functional components.

When I write it out to the console in the parent, it looks like this:

```
Parent Component date:  2021-07-20T17:21:56.359
```

I pass that date value, to another component, but when I write the value out in that child component it looks like this:

```
Child(DisplayStats) Component date:  {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
```

I'm not doing anything but passing the date value.

In the parent, the code for passing the date looks like this:

```
<DisplayStats
    dateVal={dateVal}
/>
```

And the child component, reads it like this:

```
const DisplayStats= ({
    dateVal
}) => (   //do stuff    )
```

So I'm not sure what's going on.  It's definitely messing up my app though because the API gets confused when it sees the weird date like that.

What could I be doing wrong??

Comment: are you doing any manipulation or just `console.log`?

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal just console right before I send it, and then another console log in the child right when it gets it..."console.log("Parent Component date: ", cDate");

Comment: looks like `console.log` of a component as it displays `key` and `props` and other properties. It is strange. Well a workaround could be you pass date as a string from parent and build date obj again in child component

Comment: _console log in the child right when it gets it..."console.log("Parent Component date: ", cDate");_ - what is `cDate`?

Comment: I think you have to use like this `const DisplayStats= (props) => (  props.datVal  //do stuff    )` I hop it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, in child component try to log dateVal like this:

```
console.log(this.props.dateVal)
```

You should see the correct value.